# string to byte array transformation c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I asked too many questions today but I have one more question. I'm trying to save an image into my database. I couldn't solve something. When I try to add image, it says paramater string can not be transleted into BYTE[]. Actually I'm giving bytes[] as paramater value.I tried to solve, but I couldn't find any answer maybe you can help me. Here is my code:

```
  Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

        //insert the file into database
        string strQuery = "INSERT INTO Books(Book_Name, Author_Name, Image,In_Lib) VALUES (@BN, @AN, @IM,@LIB)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        string val1 = "" + TextBox1.Text;
        string val2 = "" + TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = val1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= val2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IM", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LIB", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = "NO";
        InsertUpdateData(cmd);
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
```

Comment: may be the problem is here: _cmd.Parameters.Add("@LIB", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = "NO";_

Answer (score 4):

This line is invalid:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LIB", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = "NO";
```

Based on your SQL, it looks like you intended to use a varchar there.

Answer (score 3):

You have passed the string `"NO"` as a value of the `Binary` parameter `@LIB`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LIB", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = "NO";
```

I guess that is your problem.